# Zend Framework switching views in action

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, view

I have an action in a controller that is supposed to display different types of output depending on the value in a dropdown on a form.

I have written a Templater object (extends from Zend_View_Abstract) for the different view types.

I have tried running the following code:

```
public function generateDocumentAction()
{
    //...some code to set $view depending on post data        
    // e.g. $view = new TemplaterOdt(); //view as an OpenOffice document

    $this->_helpers->getHelper('viewRenderer')->setView($view);

    $this->view->myvar = $form->getValue('some_value');
}
```

but `$this->view` is still the default one (a Smarty templater) which which is set in /public/index.php

I've looked in the documentation to and it says you can set the view in the init() function in the controller http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.scripts.html but this would set the view for the entire controller which I don't want.

How can I change the output type for just this action?

Comment: why don't you want to set the view for the entire controller? are you calling more than one action in that controller during a single request?

Comment: I'd recommend setting this up in `Bootstrap` or controller plugin, instead of controller.

Comment: The controller is doing all stuff relating to one object in the model i.e. add, edit, delete and they need to display HTML.

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to change the template to be rendered, use:

```
$this->_helper->viewRenderer('viewscripthere');
```